# insert value to list - append not working

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string, list

I'm trying to put the value of date into the list of date_list
And I can't do that.
date gets the value from the function I created
what should I do ?

```
import pandas as pd #pandas library
from pandas_datareader import data 
import numpy as np
links_list=()
date_list=[]

links_list=get_article_links("https://www.maariv.co.il")

for link in links_list:
    date=get_Date_published(link)
    print(date) **# out-put is 30/7/20**
    date_list[link].append(date)
print(date_list)
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 14     date=get_Date_published(link)
> 15     print(date)
> ---> 16     date_list[link].append(date)
> 17 print(date_list)
> 18
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Perhaps you should use a `dict` instead?

Comment: How would you change the code ?

Comment: One way would be a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict): `date_list = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: I tried
But no output was received

Comment: Did you add `from collections import defaultdict`?

Comment: Yes I did it ..

Comment: I can't duplicate your code but a simpler version works here https://rextester.com/QMCH10451

Comment: I have to create
A list that contains only the dates.

For example: [׳30/7/20׳

Comment: Then you probably want to keep using `date_list = []` and change `date_list[link].append(date)` to `date_list.append(date)`

Answer (score 0):

try this instead: `date_list.append(date)`.
Now it appends the dates to the date_list.